# How to get Java interface @Path value from other class

Tags: java, interface, annotations

I have the following kind of interface. Is there any way to get @Path("/bucket-definitions") value "/bucket-definitions" from other class?

```
@Path("/bucket-definitions")
@Api(
    value = "Bucket definition",
    authorizations = {@Authorization("token")}
)
public interface BucketDefinitionResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/{operator-id}")
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    @ApiOperation(
        value = "Get all bucket definitions.",
        notes = "Returns all bucket definitions.",
        response = BucketDefinitionList.class
    )
    BucketDefinitionList get(@ApiParam(value = "Bucket definitions of the operator to be fetched.",required = true) @PathParam("operator-id") String var1, @ApiParam(value = "Page number",required = false) @DefaultValue("1") @QueryParam("page") Integer var2, @ApiParam("Items per page") @DefaultValue("20") @QueryParam("per_page") Integer var3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the following solution after trying in several ways. I was only interested to get the value of @Path("/bucket-definitions") that is "bucket-definitions". It is not from any website. So it is completely my way of getting the value of @Path annotation. Other experts can suggest me a better way. Hopefully, this solution will be helpful for others.

```
Annotation annotation = BucketDefinitionResource.class.getAnnotations()[0];
    if (annotation.toString().contains("Path")) {
        String SERVICE_NAME = annotation.toString().substring(annotation.toString().indexOf("/"), annotation.toString().indexOf(")"));
    }
```